# How to group by a date column by month

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with a date column where date is stored in this format:

```
2012-08-01 16:39:17.601455+0530
```

How do I `group` or `group_and_count` on this column by `month`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that SQLite won't directly recognize your dates as dates.

```
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE (DateColumn date);
INSERT INTO "YOURTABLE" VALUES('2012-01-01');
INSERT INTO "YOURTABLE" VALUES('2012-08-01 16:39:17.601455+0530');
```

If you try to use strftime() to get the month . . .

```
sqlite> select strftime('%m', DateColumn) from yourtable;
01
```

. . . it picks up the month from the first row, but not from the second.

If you can reformat your existing data as valid timestamps (as far a SQLite is concerned), you can use this relatively simple query to group by year and month. (You almost certainly don't want to group by month alone.)

```
select strftime('%Y-%m', DateColumn) yr_mon, count(*) num_dates 
from yourtable 
group by yr_mon;
```

If you can't do that, you'll need to do some string parsing. Here's the simplest expression of this idea.

```
select substr(DateColumn, 1, 7) yr_mon, count(*) num_dates 
from yourtable 
group by yr_mon;
```

But that might not quite work for you. Since you have timezone information, it's sure to change the month for some values. To get a fully general solution, I *think* you'll need to correct for timezone, extract the year and month, and so on. The simpler approach would be to look hard at this data, declare "I'm not interested in accounting for those edge cases", and use the simpler query immediately above.

Comment: Thanks. This helps with pure sqlite. We are using the sequel ruby gem. Any suggestions as to how to do it using that?

Comment: I don't think I'd try to correct for timezone within Ruby or Sequel. This kind of data manipulation has a way of going wrong in surprising ways, especially in a weakly-typed database like SQLite. But having fixed the data, you should be able to use `group` with a [complex expression method](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/SQL/ComplexExpressionMethods.html) that extracts year and month.

Comment: Ok. I get that. In which case, how do I ensure that the data entered is a valid TimeStamp (from SQLite's perspective)? The way the data got inserted was something like this - <table>.insert(:created_at => Time.now). Can you suggest a way to make the timestamps valid? I can run some 'migrations' and correct it. (By the way, all my entries have detailed date, time and timezone information)

Comment: For new timestamps, use set the default timezone to UTC: `Sequel.default_timezone = :utc`. For existing timestamps, I don't have a good idea. I think your best bet is to look for a gem that does the conversion. It's not just dead simple in the general case.

Comment: Thanks @CatCall, for pointing me in the right direction, although it took me quite a while to completely grasp the importance of what you mentioned. I ended up asking [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382855/extracting-month-year-from-time-column-in-sqlite3-using-sequel) before I finally stumbled upon the answer and understood your reply correctly! Thanks for your help.

Comment: "...it took me quite a while to completely grasp the importance of what you mentioned." I have that problem a lot. I'm glad you finally got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find the correct expression using Sequel. What I did was this:

Assuming a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE acct (date_time datetime, reward integer)
```

Then you can access the aggregated data as follows:

```
ds = DS[:acct]
ds.select_group(Sequel.function(:strftime, '%Y-%m', :date_time))
   .select_append{sum(:reward)}.each do |row|
  p row
end
```