# How to extract the month/year from Time column in SQLite3 using Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a table like this:

```
db = Sequel.sqlite
db.create_table? :timesheets do
    primary_key :id
    String      :project
    Time        :start
end
```

where I insert a record like so:

```
db[:timesheets].insert(:project => 'AAA', :start  => Time.now)
```

How would I extract the "year" from the entry? I tried the following:

```
db[:timesheets].select(:strftime.sql_function('%Y', :start)).filter(:id => 1).first
db[:timesheets].select(Sequel.extract(:month, :start)).filter(:id => 1).first
db.fetch("SELECT strftime('%Y', start) FROM timesheets;").first
```

but none of them seemed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I finally figured it out after many days of head banging.

`Time.now` does return the Time value in the standardized date format that SQLite can take. However, if the Time Zone information is encoded in it, it becomes a non-standard format.

That is, if `Time.now` gives you  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSS`,  then you're okay:

```
2012-09-12 16:34:31.331394
```

But if it gives you something like  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSS +TimeZone`:

```
2012-09-12 16:34:31.331394+0530
```

then you're in trouble.

In case you need to encode the TimeZone also, you need to convert it:

```
Time.now.xmlschema
```

which will give you something like:

```
2012-09-12T16:40:45+05:30
```

which SQLite can then parse intelligently.

Hence, the INSERT statement in the question becomes:

```
db[:timesheets].insert(:project => 'AAA', :start  => Time.now.xmlschema)
```

Now, the following queries work fine:

```
db[:timesheets].select(:strftime.sql_function('%Y', :start)).filter(:id => 2)
db[:timesheets].select(:start.extract(:month)).filter(:id => 2)
db[:timesheets].fetch("SELECT strftime('%Y', start) FROM timesheets;")
```

Comment: Good find. Since [iso8601](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-iso8601) is an alias for xmlschema, I think I might prefer to see `Time.now.iso8601` in production code. I think most programmers who deal with time know that ISO 8601 has to do with time formats. Seeing "xmlschema" in that context is a little surprising, and I'd probably stop to look it up.